# PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function createQueryBuilder() on a non-object

Tags: php, codeigniter, doctrine

What i Need :

- controller should call entities and fetch data from database.

here is my code:

controller

```
class Tweet extends CI_Controller 
{


function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
 }




function abc()
{
    $obj=new Tweet_unpublish($this->doctrine->em);

    // echo "abc";
    $obj->check(1);

    echo $obj;

}


 }
```

model

```
Class Tweet_unpublish
{   
  private $em;

 function check($emt)
 {




            $i=0;$max_result=30;
            $qb=$this->em->createQueryBuilder();
             $from = 'Entities\Tweets';
             $qb->select('select eventId')
            ->add('from', $from)
            ->setFirstResult($i)
            ->setMaxResults($max_result);
             $query = $qb->getQuery();
             echo $query->getSQl();
             $results = $query->getResult();
             print_r($results);
```

}

}
* problem im facing how t i cannot fetch data from database in doctrine.
* i  have tried t debug the code  call controller/functioname  then im getting 500 internal server error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know doctrine, but it seems like you forget to load the model in your controller and it looks like you do not use correctly the model :

```
...
function abc(){
$this->load->model("tweet_unpublish");
$this->tweet_unpublish->check(...)
....
```

Answer (score 0):

You use the not initalized private $em variable instead of the one from the parameter of the method "check".

wrong:

```
        $qb=$this->em->createQueryBuilder();
```

correct:

```
        $qb=$em->createQueryBuilder();
```